# beforeAjaxUpdate on delete cgridview yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview

Here is my code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'dsfsd',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'cssFile' => false,
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-striped',
    'beforeAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id,options){$.blockUI({
                            message: "Please wait",
                            //showOverlay: false,
                            css: {
                                border: "none",
                                padding: "15px",
                                "-webkit-border-radius": "10px",
                                "-moz-border-radius": "10px",
                                opacity: 1,
                                "z-index": "9999"
                            }
                        });}',
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => '#',
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id),array("abc/m/".CHtml::encode($data->id)."/info"))',
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '40px'),
            'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'id', array('placeholder' => 'search by id')),
        ), array(
            'header' => 'First name',
            'name' => '$data.user.f_name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->user->f_name)',
        ), array(
            'header' => 'Last name',
            'name' => '$data.user.l_name',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->user->l_name)'
        ),

        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{update} {delete}',
            //'updateButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("abc/xyz?id=".$data->id."&c_id=".$data->c_id)',
            'deleteButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("xyv/abc",array("uid"=>$data->id))',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Well, what I want is that the operations under beforeAjaxUpdate will work only when delete button is clicked, not for any other ajax actions like on search or update. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add callback function to delete button:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail

You should set `click` option in buttons config array:

```
'columns' => array(    
 ...
 'buttons'=>array(
     'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
     'template'=>'{delete}{update}',
     'buttons'=>array(
         'delete'=>array(
             'click'=>'function(){/*your code here*/}'
         )
     )
  )
  ...
)
```

You can return `false` from callback function to prevent deleting.

Comment: Im not sure about this. This overwrite the default action on click, which I dont want. What I want is to replace the loader and show my own waiting message while the asynchronous request is made.

Comment: @iThink This not overwrite default action. If you return `true` from callback function ajax request will be performed, but you wont see confirmation message. You can implement your own confirmation, replace the loader and show your own waiting message (and hide it in `afterAjaxUpdate`).